# Java cannot have a static class inside an inner class?

Tags: java, class, static, nested

**SOLVED:** Question is now solved thanks to @Pshemo: **The issue does not occur in Java 16 or above, after the rules were changed.**

**Problem:** Java allows static nested classes inside an outer class, and allows further static nested classes inside those static nested classes. It also allows non-static ("inner") classes nested inside an outer class. But for some reason I can't make a static class nested inside an inner class.

**Why does the following code fail to compile?**

```
class Outer
{
    // OK
    static class Static
    {
        // OK
        static class StaticDoubleNested
        {
        }
    }

    // OK
    class Inner
    {
        // BAD
        // "error: modifier static not allowed here"
        static class StaticDoubleNested
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Research:** I searched around the web and found nothing indicating that you can't put a static class inside an inner class, and the error message the compiler was giving (noted in the example code comment) didn't seem to help when used as part of the search terms. I'm a Java noob using Cherry Audio Voltage Module Designer as the environment (which I believe uses Java 13 regardless of what JDK is installed), so didn't know how to compile/run example code from command line, and instead tried it in an online compiler which turned out to be even older and so confused the issue. Also I never suspected for a moment that something so seemingly basic to the language would only just be changed in the last couple of years, and at the same time would be hard to find anything about on the internet. It seems I fell into all the traps!

Comment: What is your Java version? I don't remember when it changed (my guess is around Java 14) but in Java 17 it compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks, please forgive me I am a bit unsure but I think it's version 16.0.1, and also happens on the one found here: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: If you execute code like `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` on this site you will see version on which it is working, and based on result `11.0.11` it is Java 11 so before those rules changed.

Comment: I added that to the log output, and it says version 13.0.2, so I guess my command-line javac is a newer version than what the IDE is using, which is pretty old, thanks so much @Pshemo!

Comment: You are welcome. BTW it is probably not your IDE which is using old version, but your *project* is configured to use it (but IDE may also require updating). Try changing Java version in your project configuration to something newer (like Java 17 since this is current LTS).

Comment: I installed the JDK recommended at the time, thinking that I can't use a newer one, but it appears I can install a newer one, thanks again!

Comment: Welcome jc_lounge. Please note [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I see the comments elicited the necessary details. Consider updating your question so it can be answered and then you can accept the correct answer.

Comment: That isn't my downvote so I'd only be speculating jc_lounge. For me, "_Java static class inside inner class_" isn't a question. Further, you haven't provided the specifics of your environment such that I can set-up and reproduce your issue. You've also provided no specific error text nor have you noted any of your research. Help us help you. Again, welcome. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ScottWelker, I have attempted to make it a bit better, also indicating how I failed in my research so others may learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As your inner class and outer class are calling the same (static) methode "static class StaticDoubleNested" coulde it be that the inner class methode is only Overriding the outer class methode?

If that`s the case then interfaces or abstract classes will be your choice.

Comment: Thanks, but from what @Pshemo said in the comments above, it's because I'm using an older version of Java.